# Dojo. Show search status

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a search function that takes approx 10 seconds to run through the database. Is there a way to display the search status in dojo so that the user knows the search is actually being performed?

**To clarify**

Looking for something that either shows a progress bar with a percentage, a spinning circle, or just a simple Searching... within the window where the results will show, so that the user will know that their button click actually triggered the search and then disappears when the search is complete and the window is populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awful question by the way, you need to provide more information on what you actually want to achieve.

With that said, I'll take a guess that you probably want to use a Standby widget in order to blank out the page.

### Solution 1 - Standby widget

Before you perform your search, you can show the standby widget.

For example:

```
 <div data-dojo-props="target: dojo.byId("someTargetNode")" data-dojo-type="dojox/widget/Standby" id="standby" ></div>
```

You could then display the Standby widget which will overlay your target domNode with a loader by calling show(); You obviously then have to manually call hide when you get your response back as well.

```
dijit.byId("standby").show();
```

Demo of [dojox/widget/Standby](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.8.1/dojo-release-1.8.1/dojox/widget/tests/test_Standby.html) (Be patient for the page to load. The demo is unbuilt version of Dojo so can take a few seconds);

### Solution 2 - Toaster Widget

The second solution you could use is a Toaster widget, that pops out from the page to show that you are loading something.

Demo of [dojox/widget/Toaster](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.8.1/dojo-release-1.8.1/dojox/widget/tests/test_Toaster.html)

On my application I use a custom styled Toaster to achieve the loading.

**Example of using the Standby Widget**

Here is a quick screenshot of a Standby

[image]

**Example of using a Toaster**

Here is a quick screenshot of a Toaster

[image]